# Javascript variables

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I'm learning Javascript right now. Can anybody tell me why the second code block traces a empty path for -launch(this)- but using the first code block it gives me the right path?

```
"<form action='"+launchwebsite+"/subsite/' method='post' target='_blank' onsubmit='launch(this)'>"
```

and this not:

```
"<a onclick='launch(this)' title='launch' class='iblack' /></a></div>"
```

Best
Uli

Comment: What do you mean by "traces an empty path"?

Answer (score 3):

The `this` refers to the the element it is attached to. In the first snippet it is the `<form>`- and in the second the `<a>`-element. Also the `<a>` lacks a `href`-attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure but if the code you put is exactly what you are testing you are missing a ;

```
<a onclick='launch(this)' title='launch' class='iblack' /></a></div>  <-- You're Version
<a onclick='launch(this);' title='launch' class='iblack' /></a></div>
```

Else I never really did an onclick on a  html control I usually do href="" to call another page php per exemple and in that page to the treatment I want.

Another point I`ve looked at is to catch this command in javascript you would need you  to call and "blank" page as of

`<a href="#" onClick='launch(this);' title='launch' class='iblack' /></a></div>`

This last code acutally worked for me! Keep me in touch, wanna see if this works out for you!!

Patrick

Comment: What I'm trying to archive is to have the functionality of the form action `<form action='"+launchwebsite+"/subsite/' method='post' target='_blank' onsubmit='launch(this)'>` but with a link instead. (like <a href or <a onclick) I'm not sure how to convert it.

Comment: @Uli 
I'd say that on this situation use php and do it like this                

`<a href="<?php echo($launchwebsite); ?>" title='launch' class='iblack'></a>`